# Using .equals() to compare two object's variables

Tags: java, object, equals

I need to search a collection of Objects and find which object contains a 'name' variable that matches the String I read in.  Below is what each Student object looks like:

```
public Student(String name, String class)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.class = class;
}
```

I also wrote this `.equals()` method in the employee class to do my object comparison.

```
public boolean equals(Student student)
{
    return this.name.equals(student.name); 
}
```

Up in my main class I convert the student's name into a `Student` object and use the `.equals()` method to compare is to each of the other students.

```
public static void loadStudentProjects(ArrayList students)
Student currentStudent;
String studentName = "name";

  while (count < students.size())
  {
    currentStudent = Students.create(studentName); 
 //The Student object is initialized as (name, null)

System.out.println(currentStudent.equals(students.get(count)));
count++;
```

This code returns false for every comparison even though I know the first comparison should show a match for the names.  I've been told I'm required to convert the String name I'm comparing to an object and to use a `.equals()` method, but I cannot find a way to make it work.

Comment: please make sure your code compiles. you can't use "class" as a parameter name

Comment: please paste complete function `loadStudentProjects`. Also why do you have `.equals` for `Student` in `Employee` class? Typo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are *overloading* the equals method, not overriding it. It should look more like

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    ...
}
```

---

In your case, to check if an arbitrary Object `o` is equal to `this` student, you want to

1. Check that `o` is indeed a `Student` instance.
2. Presuming *1* is true, check that `o` and `this` have the name.

So you could try something along the lines of

```
(o instanceof Student) && name.equals(((Student) o).name)
```

Comment: this is one great reason to _always_ use the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Maybe providing some info in order to OP could use the `equals` overloaded method because is seems confused: *The question specifically said to use .equals() but I cannot determine a way to do so*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `equals` I suggest you to use `compareTo` (or `compareToIgnoreCase`):

```
public int compareTo(Student s) {
    return this.name.compareTo(s.name);
}
```

`compareTo` returns `0`  if the strings are equal, and a number different from `0` in any other case.

To compare to `Student` objects, you can use something like this:

```
public void aMethod(ArrayList students) {
    Student aStudent;
    int count;
    count = 0;

    aStudent = newStudent("name", "class") // Construct the Student object with the appropriate parameters
    for (Student s : students) {
        if s.compareTo(aStudent) == 0 {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: The question specifically said to use .equals() but I cannot determine a way to do so.

Comment: @DexterPeters That's why the first line implies it is a suggestion